# Algorithm for connecting set of points?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Suppose we are given a set of N points (xi,yi) in the real plane.

We want to connect them with any number of lines, such that for every pair of points A, B - there is a path from A to B (possibly indirectly through another point) - and the total length of the lines is minimal.

For example, suppose these are towns in a desert and we are constructing a road network.  We want to use the minimum amount of materials to construct the roads but still have every town reachable by road.

For N = 2 the solution is of course simply a line segment between the two points:

```
+------------------+
```

For N = 3, suppose the points are colinear, then the solution is again one line segment:

```
+------+-----------+
```

For N = 3, suppose the points would make the vertexes of an equilateral triangle, then we would add a point in the center and then construct three line segments connecting the new central point to each of the three points:

```
         +
         |
         |
        / \
       /   \
      /     \
     +       +
```

I'm sure the problem and its solution should be well-studied.  Does the problem and/or algorithm have a name?

Comment: Possible [minimal spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)? More specifically [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree)?

Comment: If each point is a possible search point, is the solution to this all the paths found by a Dijkstra search (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)?

Comment: @RogerRowland: Maybe related, but notice in the N=3 example above, a new "fake" vertex was added to the graph.  How do we select where to place these new vertexes?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos well that looks like a separate constraint - do you mean you only want one entry and one exit from each "real" vertex and you add intermediates for splitting?

Comment: @RogerRowland: Each point can be the endpoint of multiple line segments, but each line segment doesn't have to end at one of the original points in the set as for the N=3 example.  I'll add another example.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos hmmm, sounds under-constrained at first thought - but maybe considering some sort of energy minimisation model with nodes and edges represented by masses and springs respectively might be a way forward (thinking out loud and trying not to head towards finite element models).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, never one to pass up easy rep ...

Consider [the Steiner tree problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem) which seems to describe your problem more closely than the minimal spanning tree.  To quote from that article:

> The difference between the Steiner tree problem and the minimum
>   spanning tree problem is that, in the Steiner tree problem, extra
>   intermediate vertices and edges may be added to the graph in order to
>   reduce the length of the spanning tree.

Comment: Yes, and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) it remarks that the Steiner Tree is known to be NP-Complete.

Comment: Bang on.  I'd also point out that GeoSteiner is usually a good thing to use if you actually want to solve these things.